# How to insert a document with a referenced document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this 2 documents:

```
Contry {
    code : integer
    name: string
}
```

and

```
State {
    code : integer
    name: string
    contry: DBRef to Contry
}
```

I'm doing this, to insert a Contry and a State for that country (using mongo shell):

```
// insert a new country
db.country.insert({ code : 1, name: 'Brasil' });

// find the country by code
var brasilId = db.country.find({ code : { $eq: 1} }).toArray()[0]._id;

// create a DBRef object for that country
var brasilRef = { $ref: 'country', $id: brasilId };

// insert the state referencing the country
db.state.insert({ code : 1, state: 'SC', country: brasilRef });
```

This it correct?

There are a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved using:

```
var countryId = Object();
db.country.insert({ _id: countryId, code: 1, name: 'Brasil' });
db.state.insert({ code: 1, name: 'SC', contry : { $ref: 'country', $id: countryId } });
```

Comment: More details on the official documentation for DBRefs : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation

Answer (score 8):

From [the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/):

> MongoDB applications use one of two methods for relating documents:
>
> - [Manual references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references) where you save the _id field of one document in another document as a reference. Then your application can run a second query to return the related data. These references are simple and sufficient for most use cases.
> - [DBRefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation) are references from one document to another using the value of the first document’s _id field, collection name, and, optionally, its database name. By including these names, DBRefs allow documents located in multiple collections to be more easily linked with documents from a single collection.

Here, as your country code will always relate to entries in the `country` collection, you *don't need* a DBRef. In addition, if I assume the `code` to be an *unique* key (is it is fact your `_id` ?), you might simply use:

```
db.country.insert({ code : 1, name: 'Brasil' });
db.state.insert({ code : 1, state: 'SC', country: 1 });
//                                                ^
//                                  a reference to country with code 1
```

That being said, depending your use case, using a proper [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) might be a better idea:

```
oid = ObjectId()
db.country.insert({ _id: oid, code : 1, name: 'Brasil' });
db.state.insert({ code : 1, state: 'SC', country: oid });
```

Comment: Using this `oid = ObjectId()
db.country.insert({ _id: oid, code : 1, name: 'Brasil' });
db.state.insert({ code : 1, state: 'SC', country: { $ref: 'country', $id : oid } });`. Can you add this to your answer?

Comment: @BetoNeto Feel free to post you _own_ answer -- you may even self-accept it ! That way, future visitors will have choice between various options, and will be able to express their opinion by voting up or down.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works in PyMongo 4.0.2, using Python 3.7.12:

```python
country = db['country']
state = db['state']
country.insert_one({'code': 1, 'name': 'Brasil' })
state.insert_one({
  'code'   : 1, 
  'state'  : 'SC',
  'country': country.find({'code': 1})[0] 
})
```